# asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC Set launchUrl to Web Server url not using IP or localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1, appsettings

I'm trying to understand how to set the launchUrl in appsettings to test a new app via a test server.

I've done this previously when provided an IP and Port but this time I've been provided a physical url and when I asked about IP:Port etc I was told they dont use that method?

example of the url provided is https://server.apps.coName/test/appName

Any help on this would be much appreciated.